# how can I divide or chop audio file using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, audiotoolbox

I am working on a project which record audio files, now I have to send these files using email for the purpose of attachment I want to chop the audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1730/_index.html), it covers such things as exporting audio files within time range limits. Also includes fade effect for the end of the audio.. It's pretty neat.